# Onedrive and latex compiling conflict

Tags: cloud

There are warnings about overwriting the new .tex file by the old one if you compile it and if it is in onedrive. Trying to keep both .tex files, system generates XX(origin file name)-(computer name).tex in the same position.
How to solve this frustrating situation?

Answer (score 4):

Because I use a school account, in `settings-->office` the option box is auto-clicked. I found that after I un-clicked it, the issue was solved. Waste some time.

[image: onedrive setting]

Answer (score 3):

When you compile the TEX file it saves it and creates many other aux files in the process.

I have found that many times when working on cloud services such as One/Dropbox/Google Drive the sync starts before all files are written, this creates duplicities and generates errors.

To solve this you can either pause syncing before compiling. Or, and this is what I did, set up a git service so you could push/pull to the cloud rather than it syncing automatically